# Переименование переменной

Tags: matlab

Возможно ли переименовать переменную? Не переприсвоить и удалить начальную, а именно переименовать, без дополнительного использования памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя. А зачем? Разве есть язык где это возможно?